# jQuery ajax redirect issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following script to to load pages of my site:

```
var xhr;
function Ajax(afile,adiv,arun,loader) {
// Loading info
if(loader==null) { gi("loaderdiv").style.display='inline'; }

// Process Ajax
var htm = afile.split('?');
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: htm[0],
    data: htm[1],
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        gi("loaderdiv").style.display='none';

        $(gi(adiv)).fadeIn(100);
    $('#'+adiv).html(html);
    }
});
// Set global process ID
window['xhr'] = xhr;

}
```

This script works fine - most of the time.
Unfortuntately it sometimes happens that the script will redirect to the link instead of loading it into the div. When that happens, the following script error occures:

attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
jquery.js line: 16

I really hope someone can help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook was doing the redirect due to lack of session in facebook.php

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be rendering a script that is received from the page you are acquiring via ajax.

Try to put a breakpoint on the success function in your ajax request, and see what's coming back. Look for javascript, or something that might cause the page to redirect...

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm sorry, but i propably forgot to mention my lack of skills when it comes to stuff like this, so perhaps you could explain to me a little more detailed ?

Thank you again

Comment: which browser are you using ? First, in order to debug these kinds of scripts, I would download FireFox and get the FireBug extension to go with. This is out of the scope of this question, so i could only suggest you try reading about it on the net :

Comment: http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/screencast/firebug-js/
http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/30/firebug-tutorial-script-tab-javascript-debugging
http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/06/introduction-to-firebug/

Comment: Hi again. I am using firebug, and the error message from above was retrieved from there. The question is if it would be possible to add something to the code, to force the script NOT to go to the actual url?